# Cannot update or delete a parent row

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
CREATE DATABASE BOOKMANAGEMENTSYSTEM;

USE BOOKMANAGEMENTSYSTEM;

CREATE TABLE Employee (
emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
emp_name VARCHAR(20),
emp_role VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer (
cust_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
cust_name VARCHAR(20),
cust_add VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE Supplier (
supp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
supp_name VARCHAR(20),
supp_contact VARCHAR(40)
);

CREATE TABLE Book (
book_id INT,
book_price DECIMAL(10, 2),
genre VARCHAR(25),
book_name VARCHAR(20),  
PRIMARY KEY (book_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Inventory (
inventory_id INT,
category VARCHAR(20),
selling_price DECIMAL(10, 2),
PRIMARY KEY (inventory_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Invoice (
invoice_id INT,
supp_id INT,
book_id INT,
inventory_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Payment (
pay_id INT,
item_qty INT,
Tprice DECIMAL (10,2),
order_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY (pay_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Orders (
order_id INT,
order_qty INT,
date DATE,
inventory_id INT,
book_id INT,
cust_id INT,
emp_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY (order_id)
);

ALTER TABLE Invoice
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Invoice_Book FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES Book (book_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Invoice_Supplier FOREIGN KEY (supp_id) REFERENCES Supplier (supp_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Invoice_Inventory FOREIGN KEY (inventory_id) REFERENCES Inventory (inventory_id);

ALTER TABLE Payment  
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Payment_Orders FOREIGN KEY (order_id)  
REFERENCES Orders (order_id);

ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Inventory FOREIGN KEY (inventory_id) REFERENCES Inventory (inventory_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Book FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES Book (book_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Customer FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES Customer (cust_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Employee FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES Employee (emp_id);

INSERT INTO Employee (emp_id, emp_name, emp_role)
VALUES ('101', 'Amirul', 'Cashier'),
       ('102', 'Nurin', 'Store Manager'),
       ('103', 'Diana', 'Admin'),
       ('104', 'Faris', 'Inventory Manager'),
       ('105', 'Christy', 'Sales Coordinator');

INSERT INTO Customer (cust_id, cust_name, cust_add)
VALUES ('201', 'Nuria', 'Taman Mawar, 88400'),
       ('202', 'Stephan', 'Taman Lily, 88400'),
       ('203', 'Khairul', 'Taman Kemboja, 88400'),
       ('204', 'Maria', 'Taman Tulip, 88400'),
       ('205', 'Rina', 'Taman Bunga Raya, 88400');

INSERT INTO Supplier (supp_id, supp_name, supp_contact)
VALUES ('301', 'Scholastic', 'scholastic@book.com'),
       ('302', 'Karya Seni', 'karyaseni@book.com'),
       ('303', 'Simon & Schuster', 'simonschuster@book.com'),
       ('304', 'Bloomsbury', 'bloomsbury@book.com'),
       ('305', 'HarperVia', 'harpervia@book.com');

INSERT INTO Book (book_id, book_price, genre, book_name)
VALUES ('401', '25.50', 'young adult', 'Thea Stilton'),
       ('402', '20.20', 'drama', 'Twisted fate'),
       ('403', '32.70', 'comedy', 'Dork diaries'),
       ('404', '45.60', 'fantasy', 'Harry Potter'),
       ('405', '27.00', 'non-fiction', 'Almond');

INSERT INTO Inventory (inventory_id, category, selling_price)
VALUES ('501', 'young adult fiction', '28.50'),     ('502', 'adult fiction', '25.20'),
('503', 'young adult fiction', '35.70'),
('504', 'adult fiction', '50.60'),
('505', 'adult non-fiction', '30.00');

INSERT INTO Invoice (invoice_id, supp_id, book_id, inventory_id)
VALUES ('00001', '301', '401', '501'),
('00002', '302', '402', '502'),
('00003', '303', '403', '503'),
('00004', '304', '404', '504'),
('00005', '305', '405', '505');

INSERT INTO Orders (order_id, order_qty, date, inventory_id, book_id, cust_id, emp_id)
VALUES ('10001', '1', '2024-01-11', '501', '401', '201', '101'),
('10002', '2', '2024-01-12', '502', '402', '202', '102'),
('10003', '1', '2024-01-13', '503', '403', '203', '103'),
('10004', '2', '2024-01-14', '504', '404', '204', '104'),
('10005', '1', '2024-01-15', '505', '405', '205', '105');

INSERT INTO Payment (pay_id, item_qty, Tprice, order_id)
VALUES ('20001', '1', '28.50', '10001'),
('20002', '2', '50.40', '10002'),
('20003', '1', '35.70', '10003'),
('20004', '2', '101.20', '10004'),
('20005', '1', '30.00', '10005');

DELETE FROM Employee WHERE emp_id = 103;
DELETE FROM Employee WHERE emp_id = 105;

UPDATE Employee SET emp_role = 'Sales Coordinator' WHERE emp_id = 101;
UPDATE Employee SET emp_role = 'Admin' WHERE emp_id = 104;
UPDATE Employee SET emp_role = 'Inventory Manager' WHERE emp_id = 102;
```

I tried to delete and update items in the Employee Table, but it shows the following errors. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bookmanagementsystem`.`orders`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Orders_Employee` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`) REFERENCES `Employee` (`emp_id`)) I have tried to delete the item from other table first too, but it doesn't work. I also tried to update each table that have the same attribute but it still appear to be error.

Comment: So, the whole point of having a foreign key at all is to ensure that your Orders ALWAYS has a valid Employee ID.  If you want to be able to remove employees without changing Orders, then 1. don't create a foreign key, or 2. Change/reassign all orders for that employee before deleting, or 3. Don't delete employees at all.  Inactivate them instead.  4. Delete all orders belonging to that employee before deleting the employee.  That last is the worst of all the alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solve your question.**

You need to add `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint when you add the FOREIGN KEYS like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Payment  
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Payment_Orders FOREIGN KEY (order_id)  
REFERENCES Orders (order_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Remember ON DELETE CASCADE is used to specify that when a row is deleted from the parent table, all rows in the child table that reference the deleted row should also be deleted

Solution added to your query:

```
CREATE DATABASE BOOKMANAGEMENTSYSTEM;

USE BOOKMANAGEMENTSYSTEM;

CREATE TABLE Employee (
emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
emp_name VARCHAR(20),
emp_role VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer (
cust_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
cust_name VARCHAR(20),
cust_add VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE Supplier (
supp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
supp_name VARCHAR(20),
supp_contact VARCHAR(40)
);

CREATE TABLE Book (
book_id INT,
book_price DECIMAL(10, 2),
genre VARCHAR(25),
book_name VARCHAR(20),  
PRIMARY KEY (book_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Inventory (
inventory_id INT,
category VARCHAR(20),
selling_price DECIMAL(10, 2),
PRIMARY KEY (inventory_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Invoice (
invoice_id INT,
supp_id INT,
book_id INT,
inventory_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Payment (
pay_id INT,
item_qty INT,
Tprice DECIMAL (10,2),
order_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY (pay_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Orders (
order_id INT,
order_qty INT,
date DATE,
inventory_id INT,
book_id INT,
cust_id INT,
emp_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY (order_id)
);

ALTER TABLE Invoice
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Invoice_Book FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES Book (book_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Invoice_Supplier FOREIGN KEY (supp_id) REFERENCES Supplier (supp_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Invoice_Inventory FOREIGN KEY (inventory_id) REFERENCES Inventory (inventory_id);

ALTER TABLE Payment  
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Payment_Orders FOREIGN KEY (order_id)  
REFERENCES Orders (order_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Inventory FOREIGN KEY (inventory_id) REFERENCES Inventory (inventory_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Book FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES Book (book_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Customer FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES Customer (cust_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Employee FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES Employee (emp_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

INSERT INTO Employee (emp_id, emp_name, emp_role)
VALUES ('101', 'Amirul', 'Cashier'),
       ('102', 'Nurin', 'Store Manager'),
       ('103', 'Diana', 'Admin'),
       ('104', 'Faris', 'Inventory Manager'),
       ('105', 'Christy', 'Sales Coordinator');

INSERT INTO Customer (cust_id, cust_name, cust_add)
VALUES ('201', 'Nuria', 'Taman Mawar, 88400'),
       ('202', 'Stephan', 'Taman Lily, 88400'),
       ('203', 'Khairul', 'Taman Kemboja, 88400'),
       ('204', 'Maria', 'Taman Tulip, 88400'),
       ('205', 'Rina', 'Taman Bunga Raya, 88400');

INSERT INTO Supplier (supp_id, supp_name, supp_contact)
VALUES ('301', 'Scholastic', 'scholastic@book.com'),
       ('302', 'Karya Seni', 'karyaseni@book.com'),
       ('303', 'Simon & Schuster', 'simonschuster@book.com'),
       ('304', 'Bloomsbury', 'bloomsbury@book.com'),
       ('305', 'HarperVia', 'harpervia@book.com');

INSERT INTO Book (book_id, book_price, genre, book_name)
VALUES ('401', '25.50', 'young adult', 'Thea Stilton'),
       ('402', '20.20', 'drama', 'Twisted fate'),
       ('403', '32.70', 'comedy', 'Dork diaries'),
       ('404', '45.60', 'fantasy', 'Harry Potter'),
       ('405', '27.00', 'non-fiction', 'Almond');

INSERT INTO Inventory (inventory_id, category, selling_price)
VALUES ('501', 'young adult fiction', '28.50'),     ('502', 'adult fiction', '25.20'),
('503', 'young adult fiction', '35.70'),
('504', 'adult fiction', '50.60'),
('505', 'adult non-fiction', '30.00');

INSERT INTO Invoice (invoice_id, supp_id, book_id, inventory_id)
VALUES ('00001', '301', '401', '501'),
('00002', '302', '402', '502'),
('00003', '303', '403', '503'),
('00004', '304', '404', '504'),
('00005', '305', '405', '505');

INSERT INTO Orders (order_id, order_qty, date, inventory_id, book_id, cust_id, emp_id)
VALUES ('10001', '1', '2024-01-11', '501', '401', '201', '101'),
('10002', '2', '2024-01-12', '502', '402', '202', '102'),
('10003', '1', '2024-01-13', '503', '403', '203', '103'),
('10004', '2', '2024-01-14', '504', '404', '204', '104'),
('10005', '1', '2024-01-15', '505', '405', '205', '105');

INSERT INTO Payment (pay_id, item_qty, Tprice, order_id)
VALUES ('20001', '1', '28.50', '10001'),
('20002', '2', '50.40', '10002'),
('20003', '1', '35.70', '10003'),
('20004', '2', '101.20', '10004'),
('20005', '1', '30.00', '10005');

DELETE FROM Employee WHERE emp_id = 103;
DELETE FROM Employee WHERE emp_id = 105;

UPDATE Employee SET emp_role = 'Sales Coordinator' WHERE emp_id = 101;
UPDATE Employee SET emp_role = 'Admin' WHERE emp_id = 104;
UPDATE Employee SET emp_role = 'Inventory Manager' WHERE emp_id = 102;
```

Result of the query:
[image]

Comment: In real-world production data bases you should NEVER use Delete Cascade.  It almost always is responsible for massive losses of useful data because someone thought they no longer needed a master key.

Comment: What about having soft delete implemented to the project ?